# how to replace every occurrence of [some_text](some_text) with [[some_text]](some_text) in javascript

Tags: javascript

note I need to do this replacement only for the words that conform to this pattern `@[some_text](some_text)`

 here are some examples of inputs and the expected output:

 input : `thanks @[said](said_Id) for helping me with [PCM]` 

output : `thanks @[[said]](said_Id) for helping me with [PCM]` 


 input : `thanks @[said](said_Id) @[john](jhon_doe_id)`

output : `thanks @[[said]](said_Id) @[[jhon]](jhon_does_id)` 


 input : `thanks @[said](said_Id) some text @[john](jhon_doe_id) some text @[alex](alex-id)` 

output : `thanks @[[said]](said_Id) @[[jhon]](jhon_does_id)  some text @[[alex]](alex-id)`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to split the string based on " @[" then creating a new string but it just seems like a wacky way of doing this I guess this could be done using String.replace and some regex

Comment: I only want to replace the [said] part to [[said]],basically wrapping it in an additional bracket layer

Comment: [1] What should be the result of `[[some text] (....)`?  (2) Can you have nested brackets?

Comment: ```[[some text]] (....)``` is the output I want currently I have ```[some text] (....)```as the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input.replace(/@\[(.*?)\](\(.*?\))/g, '@[[$1]]$2')
```

The regex broken out:

```
@\[(.*?)\]  <-- match the pattern @[anything]  
(\(.*?\))  <--- match (anything)
/@\[(.*?)\](\(.*?\))/g  <--- globally match all @[anything](anything)
```

The replace portion takes the subjects in parenthesis from the search and replaces them in order of appearance ($1, $2) - and in this case it's rebuilding the string that it found in the search `@[[$1]]$2`

```js
const fix = input => input.replace(/@\[(.*?)\](\(.*?\))/g, '@[[$1]]$2');
console.log(fix(`thanks @[said](said_Id) for helping me with [PCM]`))
console.log(fix(`thanks @[said](said_Id) some text @[john](jhon_doe_id) some text @[alex](alex-id)`))
```

Comment: I updated the answer. I'm not the best at explaining the right terms with regex, Let me know if that doesnt clear it up for you

Comment: thank you ! I never knew you could use the subjects the regex pattern found in the second param of  ```replace()``` using the $ sign